# incrementing a php variable in side a jscript dosent work

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

```
<?php
$hello[1]="A";
$hello[2]="B";
$hello[3]="C";
$hello[4]="D";
$m=1;
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var i;
<?php $m=1; ?>
for(i=1;i<5;i++)
{
document.write("<?php echo $hello[$m]; ?> <br>");
<?php $m++; ?>
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the above php code(file), it only shows the "A" letter for four times. i want it to read all elements in the "hello[]" array. $m doesn't increment by one. i tried "$m=$m+1". it also doesn't work. how can i correct this?

Comment: Your PHP does not loop, so your JS will only print `A` 4 times. :) You need to put your loop in the PHP, not the JS

Comment: or are there any ways to use js variable as php array's index?

Comment: @DScript It is important to realize that PHP runs in entirety before the file is sent to the web browser. Then, JavaScript runs in the web browser. You cannot run some PHP, then some JavaScript, then some PHP, etc... Therefore, you can use PHP to generate JavaScript, but you cannot run JavaScript to do anything with PHP (until you get into Ajax - which is an entirely different topic).

Answer (score 0):

You should loop in php if you want to increase a php variable

```
<?php
$hello[1]="A";
$hello[2]="B";
$hello[3]="C";
$hello[4]="D";
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
{
?>
    document.write("<?php echo $hello[$i]; ?> <br>");
<?php
}
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give it a try, it should work however I did not try it.

Comment: actually i have no proper knowledge how php and js works. anyway. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Khan Shahrukh on this one, but seeing what you are trying to do, I think you don't really need the JS to print these variables. Maybe this would suit you more:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $hello[1]="A";
    $hello[2]="B";
    $hello[3]="C";
    $hello[4]="D";

    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
    {
        echo $hello[$i] . " <br>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It will output the desired variables directly in the page, instead of using JS (of course, it depends if you actually need it or not).

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $hello[1]="A";
    $hello[2]="B";
    $hello[3]="C";
    $hello[4]="D";
?>
<script>
<?php
    foreach($hello as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo 'document.write('.$value.');'."\n";
    }
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        document.write(A);
        document.write(B);
        document.write(C);
        document.write(D);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```